# Collapse div based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen several similar questions, but can't find a solution that works well for me. I need the collapsed content outside of the header container.  My basic set up is like so

```
<div id="buttonRow">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="row collapse-row" id="rowOne">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-custom vertical-align">
                        <div id="about-text">
                            <p>Header One</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 collapse-row" id="rowTwo">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-custom vertical-align">
                        <div id="about-text">
                            <p>Header Two</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 collapse-row" id="rowThree">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-custom vertical-align">
                        <div id="about-text">
                            <p>Header Three</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 d-none" id="ContentOne">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 d-none" id="ContentTwo">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 d-none" id="ContentThree">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if Header One is clicked, contentOne should collapse etc.  I have not done much with the Javascript yet, just obtain the id

```
$('.collapse-row').click(function() {
    var id  = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id)
});
```

What I want to try and avoid is writing separate code for each collapse.  I wanted to somehow use the id to make the correct content collapse.  What would be the best way to achieve this?

Additionally, I also have the same headers within the navigation at the top of the page.  When these ones are clicked, it should scroll down and collapse the appropriate one.  So I have to somehow fit this in as well.

I have created a demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/322/) with the basic structure.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `<div id="about-text">` appears multiple times in the document. An `id` **must be** unique.

Comment: Try something and edit your question with a specific issue. More about this on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be through the use of [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on the header elements. The data attributes will hold the target element id. A small tweak to the JS allows the d-none class to be toggled on the rows. Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/337/)

Update HTML. Notice the data-target-id attribute.

```html
<div class="row collapse-row" data-target-id="ContentOne">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-custom vertical-align">
         <div id="about-text">
              <p>Header One</p>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Update JS

```js
$('.collapse-row').click(function() {
  var id  = $(this).data("target-id");
  $("#" + id).toggleClass("d-none");
});
```